# How do I modify a window class without a window handle?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently trying to translate a few WIN32API functions to Java using JNI. One of those functions is [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Usually, I think you would specify a different callback function for every window class you register, but since I'm translating the callback to Java as well this doesn't work.

So the current plan is to append a `jobject` (defined as `_jobject*`) to the window class and work with that in the callback. Problem is: you can only change data attached to a window class using a HWND. The MSDN documentation to the best of my knowledge doesn't specify a function that can modify a window class using only a window class ATOM or the name.

Thus my question: Is there a way to change a window class (using something like [SetClassLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), without having to use a valid HWND?

**Java side** (I'll eventually add a public function that does what I actually need done):

```
public class c_winjni implements i_jnisystem {
    public interface i_wnd_proc {
        public int wnd_proc(long il_hwnd, int im_message, long im_wparam, long im_lparam);
    }

    private class c_wndclassex {
        public int im_style = 0;
        public i_wnd_proc ds_wnd_proc = null;
        public int im_cls_extra = 0;
        public int im_wnd_extra = 0;
        public long il_instance = 0L;
        public long il_icon = 0L;
        public long il_small_icon = 0L;
        public long il_cursor = 0L;
        public long il_background = 0L;
        public String str_menu_name = null;
        public String str_class_name = null;
    }

    private static native short registerClassEx(c_wndclassex ds_wcx, int[] imr_error);
}
```

**C++ side**:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK default_window_callback_proc(HWND ds_hwnd, UINT im_message, WPARAM im_w_param, LPARAM im_l_param) {
    return DefWindowProc(ds_hwnd, im_message, im_w_param, im_l_param);
}

/*
 * Class:     c_winjni
 * Method:    registerClassEx
 * Signature: (Lc_winjni/c_wndclassex;[I)S
 */
JNIEXPORT_EX jshort JNICALL Java_c_1winjni_registerClassEx
    (JNIEnv *ads_env, jclass /*jds_class*/, jobject jds_wcx, jintArray jimr_error)
JNI_CPPEXCEPTION_TRAP_BEGIN {
    c_jnienv jds_env(ads_env);

    jint *aim_error = NULL;
    if (jimr_error && jds_env.get_array_length(jimr_error) > 0) {
        aim_error = jds_env.get_array_elements(jimr_error, NULL);
    }

    WNDCLASSEX ds_wcx;
    ds_wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    ds_wcx.style = jds_env.get_int_field(jds_wcx, "im_style");

    // Imagine I'm checking whether field ds_wnd_proc in object jds_wcx is null.
    // If it is, use the default callback (as shown below).
    // If it isn't, set ds_wcx.lpfnWndProc to some other callback that reads
    // custom class data and calls a Java function of the object attached to the window class.
    ds_wcx.lpfnWndProc = default_window_callback_proc;

    ds_wcx.cbClsExtra = jds_env.get_int_field(jds_wcx, "im_cls_extra") + sizeof(LONG_PTR);
    ds_wcx.cbWndExtra = jds_env.get_int_field(jds_wcx, "im_wnd_extra");
    ds_wcx.hInstance = (HINSTANCE) jds_env.get_long_field(jds_wcx, "il_instance");
    ds_wcx.hIcon = (HICON) jds_env.get_long_field(jds_wcx, "il_icon");
    ds_wcx.hIconSm = (HICON) jds_env.get_long_field(jds_wcx, "il_small_icon");
    ds_wcx.hCursor = (HCURSOR) jds_env.get_long_field(jds_wcx, "il_cursor");
    ds_wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) jds_env.get_long_field(jds_wcx, "il_background");
    ct_jstring<TCHAR, 256> str_menu_name(ads_env, (jstring) jds_env.get_string_field(jds_wcx, "str_menu_name"));
    ds_wcx.lpszMenuName = str_menu_name.get_data();
    ct_jstring<TCHAR, 256> str_class_name(ads_env, (jstring) jds_env.get_string_field(jds_wcx, "str_class_name"));
    ds_wcx.lpszClassName = str_class_name.get_data();

    jshort result = RegisterClassEx(&ds_wcx);
    if (result == NULL && aim_error) {
        *aim_error = GetLastError();
    }

    // commit changes and invalidate pointer
    if (aim_error) {
        jds_env.release_array_elements(jimr_error, aim_error, 0);
    }
    return result;
} JNI_CPPEXCEPTION_TRAP_END2(ads_env, 0)
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is implement the solution that every good OOP wrapper to Win32 that I know of uses. But you need to take charge of the call to `RegisterClassEx`. You need to reserve some bytes in `cbWndExtra` to store your object reference. And then you can route the common window procedure to that object.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough what I'm trying to achieve: I want to map `RegisterClassEx` to some Java function using JNI. `WNDCLASSEX` contains a WndProc member, so theres a callback function _per class_ and not one callback function per window (which is what `cbWndExtra` is there for). So I'm using `cbClsExtra` to add custom data to the window class, only there's no way to change _per class_ data without having a window of that class (its like trying to access what should be a static member, only to find out its a normal field that's guaranteed to be the same for every instance).

Comment: Why are you associating callbacks to class? That makes no sense to me. You want an instance method.

Comment: @David If I were creating an abstraction, yes, but I'm really only interested in translating between C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that it is only possible to modify the extra class memory using `SetClassLongPtr`. For which you need a valid window handle.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem... A WNDCLASSEX is a class, and HWND is a handle to a window. You may think of the first as a OO class, the second as a "pointer" or "reference" an object (instance). 
Yet to modify the class, you seem to have to go through an instance of that class... Weird :) I can imagine this is the most common scenario (having the HWND) (BTW, why you don't have a HWND?)

An idea: would it be acceptable to create a window (hiddend) using the ATOM, and use the returned HWND as a "reference" for `SetClassLongPtr`?

Comment: That would work, as far as I can see. It just seems like a lot of overhead for something that should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: @Deaod agreed, but why you do not have a HWND to begin with? How can you have only a class ATOM?

Comment: I'm trying to map WIN32API functions as directly as possible to JNI functions to keep the c++ layer as flat as possible. And as far as I can see you need a class before you can even create a window using it.

Comment: @Deaod What I do not understand is why you are registering a window class with a generic function, and then later on you need to change it (or another part of the window class). Can't you defer the change until you actually have a window? Or can't you have a 1 class - 1 window - 1 wndproc relationship? (Seeing your API and how would you like to use it may help!)

Comment: I'm not trying to change something later on. I'm trying to set the class up correctly before even creating the first window. I'll add more code to my question.

Comment: @Deaod Let me see if I understand: you are trying a 1-1 mapping for each WIN32 function in a given set(right?). For RegisterClassEx, you want to have a "generic" wndproc, that will call back to java code. Therefore, it will use a jobject*. You can reserve space for the jobject* in RegisterClassEx, but you don't know how to actually set it. Have I got it?

Comment: @Deaod In that case, when do you think to set the pointer to the real thing?

Comment: I don't know how to set the `jobject` I want to store without the use of a window handle. If I had a window handle, I could use `SetClassLongPtr`. Sadly it seems that for whatever reason you can **only** change a window class by referencing it indirectly (via a window handle).

Comment: OK, but my point is: when (not how) do you want to actually store a valid jobject? Because the only "moment" in the program lifetime when you need to store a valid jobject is when you actually will use the wndproc, and you will "use" it only when you create a window (before, the wndproc will never be called). So, you can safely defer the writing of the jobject at the point in time when you will actually create a window. Just save it somewhere else, or pass it to your CreateWindow wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

As to get a valid HWND for registered class ATOM, you can use the [FindWindow function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

By passing `NULL` for the `lpWindowName` parameter you'll get a handle to the first window that matches the class. Of course you'll fail if there is no window instance present. But in this it's probably good to assume that the corresponding window class isn't registered yet.